# Failed to Persist with EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, wildfly, jta

I'm doing a project with Netbeans 8.2, JSF 2.2, JPA, EclipseLink, Maven and Primefaces.

The pattern that I am using is the Facade.

The problem that arises is that I can not persist my data. I created a simple xhtml, with a simple POJO also to do the tests, but it does not persist.

The strange thing is that I started using the Glassfish 4.1.1 that Payara brings (since the original 4.1.1 of Glassfish presents problems to love a pool of connections) and MySQL 8, then I tried the same application server but with PostgreSQL, and in both cases I can create the Pool, valid that connects correctly, which makes without problems with both databases, but when I run the application, the data does not persist.

Then I did exactly the same tests with a WildFly 12.0.0. I tried creating a pool of connections for MySQL 8 and another one for PostreSQL; checking that both connect well with the databases, but they do not persist.

I note that in no case neither of the two application servers throws me an error at runtime, it is as if everything is correct.

I'm confused.

I thank you in advance for your attention.

The POJO code is the following:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "categoria")
public class Categoria implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int codigo;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "estado")
    private boolean estado = true;

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public boolean getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(boolean estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

Controller code:

```
import com.mitocode.ejb.CategoriaFacadeLocal;
import com.mitocode.model.Categoria;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CategoriaController implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private CategoriaFacadeLocal categoriaEJB;
    private Categoria categoria;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        categoria = new Categoria();
    }

    public void registrar(){
        try{
            categoriaEJB.create(categoria);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //Mostrar mensaje de error de PrimeFaces (Growl)
        }
    }

    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

}
```

View code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:inputText label="Ingrese Categoría" value="#{categoriaController.categoria.nombre}" />
        <p:commandButton value = "Registrar" actionListener = "#{categoriaController.registrar()}"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Persistence.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="primePU" transaction-type="JTA">
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/primePG</jta-data-source>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <properties>
     <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none"/>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The AbstractFacade code:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    final Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = 
        getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

The Interface CategoriaFacadeLocal code:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Local;


@Local
public interface CategoriaFacadeLocal {

    void create(Categoria categoria);

    void edit(Categoria categoria);

    void remove(Categoria categoria);

    Categoria find(Object id);

    List<Categoria> findAll();

    List<Categoria> findRange(int[] range);

    int count();

}
```

The EJB CategoriaFacade code:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;


@Stateless
public class CategoriaFacade extends AbstractFacade<Categoria> implements 
CategoriaFacadeLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public CategoriaFacade() {
        super(Categoria.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: What about EJB code? Can you post it?

Comment: what does your debugging reveal? You know, looking in the LOG of your chosen JPA provider ...

Comment: This can't be answered without you showing us your persist code, which is the important part here.

Comment: How did you install EclipseLink? If you're including it your deployment you might want to remove it and just try RESTEasy since from the snippets it looks like you're using plain JPA.

Comment: @Nikola: I edited the post to add the code of the components of the Facade pattern.

Comment: have you tried to put commandbutton inside of <h:form> ?

Comment: also, it's more apropriate to put action instead of actionlistener, but it should work with actionlistener anyway

Comment: It was that @Nikola, I needed to frame with a <h: form>.
I apologize for having wasted your time. It is an inconceivable mistake, which happened to me.